Unable to login into wp-admin panel Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_screen_options()
I have a problem logging into the admin panel on the main site and on the subdomain where the same site was created before it was moved to the main site. I should add that both of the sites have always worked and there were no problems with them and suddenly they both have the same problem when logged into the admin panel:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_screen_options() in /home/glowup/domains/glowupstudio.pl/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:113 Stack trace: #0 /home/glowup/domains/glowupstudio.pl/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/glowup/domains/glowupstudio.pl/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php on line 113
I would add that on the subdomain wp.glowupstudio.co.uk all plugins are disabled.
Thank you in advance for your help!
Greetings
Disabled all plugins to login into panel, not working.

Try to manually upgrade your wordpress.
